# Style sections can't affect Javascript-created Elements, right? Have to do Style with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I make elements with CreateElement, and name them the same as elements supposed to be affected by a Style section in the page, they actually won't be affected?

If I want to style my JavaScript created elements, I have to do it with JavaScript, right?

Like:

```js
 test()

            function test() {
              var x = document.createElement("div");
              x.setAttribute("class", "test");
              document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
```

```css
 #test {
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            bottom:10px;
            background-color: #123456;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try `x.className = "test"` and change the CSS selector to `.test`

Comment: "If I make elements with CreateElement, and name them the same as elements supposed to be affected by a Style section in the page, they actually won't be affected?" — No. That's completely wrong. You just made a typo. (Voting to close the question because the problem is caused by a typo.). You set the `class` attribute of the element but used an `id` selector instead of a `class` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems correct except the mismatched attribute between *id* (`#`) and *class* (`.`).

If *test* is a *class* then use `.test` in CSS.

If you want the selector to be *id* then set that in the JS:

```
x.setAttribute("id", "test");
```

```css
#test {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  background-color: #123456;
}
```

```html
<script>
test()

function test() {
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.setAttribute("id", "test");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are affected.

In your code, it won't be affected because you assign it to the `test class`, while the style is referred to the `test id`.

Correct with JS:

```
x.setAttribute("id", "test");
```

Correct with CSS:

```
.test{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a CSS ID selector but give your element a CLASS.

Try

```
.test{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did small mistake here. In setAttribute please change to id instead of class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

#test {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  background-color: #123456;
}
</style>

<body>

<script>
test()

function test() {
  var x = document.createElement("div");
  x.setAttribute("id", "test");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```